# if statement and visible statement dont work but the things inside it work? ACTIONSCRIPT 3

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, visible

Yeah so here's my code

```
if(defaultmeter.visible = true)
{
meter1.visible = true;
meter1.x = 124.10;
meter.y = 63.10;
jizz.visible = false;
}
```

Thing is the things inside the { }
work but the the if statement doesnt apply 
Like when defaultmeter is not visible, the stuff inside the {} still applies :C help please

Answer (score 1):

If you do `mc.visible = true` so you assign the `true` value to `mc.visible` so you make mc visible which normally always `true`.

To compare in this level, we use `==` (equal) operator to check if two values are equal or the `!=` (not equal, different ) to check if two values are not equal.

So in your case you can do :

```
if(defaultmeter.visible == true){
    // instructions here
}
```

Or

```
if(defaultmeter.visible != false){
    // instructions here
}
```

Or simply

```
if(defaultmeter.visible){
    // instructions here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well of course, you need to cover the other case as well, like this:

```
if(defaultmeter.visible == true)
{
    meter1.visible = true;
    meter1.x = 124.10;
    meter.y = 63.10;
    jizz.visible = false;
}else{
    meter1.visible = false;
    jizz.visible = true; //btw, jizz, seriously?
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this if (defaultmeter.visible == true){}

Comment: you need to use the code like this if (defaultmeter.visible == true){//enter your matter} because true is a boolean variable and it wants == sign